# why I write a wav file in python but playing with no sound

Tags: python, scipy, waveform

I write wav file with int32 data type and sample rate is 11025, but output wav file is no sound when I playing it.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
rate, data0 = read('001.wav') #rate type is int     
data = numpy.asarray(data0,dtype=theano.config.floatX)  
for ffp in data:                    
    print data[ffp]
```

use this code we can see the normal wav file clearly.
here is some integer sequences:

`-23.0
-51.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
-17.0
39.0
253.0
-266.0
-146.0
-146.0
-56.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
43.0
177.0
-428.0
455.0
-236.0
-325.0
113.0
237.0
121.0
82.0
352.0
139.0
0.0
0.0
2.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
214.0
160.0
-733.0
-501.0
844.0
-446.0
-8.0
28.0
0.0
-1.0
-170.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
-2.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-2.0
184.0
51.0
-330.0
-80.0
416.0
-121.0
-498.0
192.0
148.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
112.0
-171.0
-253.0
-49.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-2.0
-1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-24.0
0.0
0.0
-101.0
-142.0
-476.0
-212.0
-377.0
329.0
44.0
-38.0
246.0
0.0
0.0
7.0
315.0
189.0
67.0
28.0
97.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
120.0
54.0
0.0`

and this one is playing with no sound wav file:

```
    from scipy.io.wavfile import write

    wavfiles = []

    for fr in range(wavfile.size/11025):
        for fn in range(wavfile[fr].size):
            wavfile[fr][fn] = int(wavfile[fr][fn])                                              
        wavfiles0 = numpy.asarray(wavfile[fr],dtype='int32')
        wavfiles.append(wavfiles0)

    wavfiles_ = numpy.vstack(wavfiles)        
    wavfiles2 = wavfiles_.ravel()
    filename = 'test01.wav'           
    write(filename, 11025, wavfiles2)
    for ffp in wavfiles2:                    
        print wavfiles2[ffp]
```

and we can see this integer sequences:

`-429
-288
-725
-1264
486
326
-639
-695
-632
-742
532
1063
671
71
-613
73
807
195
496
-422
-74
-564
884
-1196
558
-106
-667
975
-546
-178
-1253
-279
1021
-549
38
304
-278
-950
-264
-88
621
-460
78
-138
450
-191
370
123
599
-858
-860
95
-204
-285
-210
441
294
-225
-109
-26
-1267
-199
-950
-369
-232
348
-528
-13
495
-554
-542
1066
159
-176
-282
-1240
-298
-1304
-883
309
-574
519
-149
271
-562
-1107
-248
-161
100
-165
109
105
-267
-801
8
-346
-1065
-198
394
-538
32
-41
73
-209
-1095
1508
-520
37
139
450
-335
-60
-225
499
-63
991
-702
-733
702
-480
-828
-447
-803
978
-439
663
636
-513
42
-100
388
945
364
590
-142
1127
-950
-1052
1122
213
-94
-722
-63
-601
323
509
-692
-446
-393
-496
940
-761
311
-643
-144
-280
-162
383
-828
-198
-361
-61
-1035
-246
1167
-29
27
246
1063
-88
192
-1481
-524
457
-205
453
-198
499
-33
30
438
72
198
-17
-303
532
-282
738
712
-963
198
53
623
708
879
398
388
954
-177
-549
165
116
-359
147
410
-69
615
240
168
-745
-83
125
-858
847
930
142
-1127
465
1535
1054
-1229
711
295
266
38
146
-701
-345
-74
241
164
102
-684
-339
130
-883
-1442
-1196
124
-649
-15
-376
776
-559
73
940
-419
-48
617
20
-515
179
-1065
157
-497
202
282
-6
-104
-267
343
489
236
722
-320
1007
-466
-129
807
487
-674
-627
170
256
-856
-629
-166
-1390
1184
-303
179
-447
482
303
-502
-52
-137
395
109
280
1147
159
243
118
531
-70
-564
562
491
38
-74
-826
-63
-1276
329
-43
-41
-587
-193
-43
-52
949
-258
-446
-460
-258
332
-580
-514
-898
294
-883
-377
-428
48
0
411
970
146
410
-183
-161
-177
38
67
346
-447
-217
-998
580
-165
411`

Is any reason that causing this mistake of playing with no sound.

If the integer sequence is not a normal wav file data sequence, because of the sequences with less zero than normal one?

what I am doing is learning music, like combining 30 songs to just one song, but when I playing the one song that I made it, there is no sound.
looking for help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with scipy.io.wavfile.

But, have audio data that is an int32, that means the dynamic range should span [2147483648..-2147483647] which would make a value of 1063 have an amplitude of 4.95e-07 which should be inaudible even if your hardware could accurately render it.

I'm also puzzled by your sampling rate. At 11025 samples per second the 160 samples you show (assuming one-channel audio) would make 14 milliseconds of sound. A sound this short, even if it was at an amplitude you could hear, would almost be over before it started playing.

Comment: My sequences is a short cut of all.cause that is too many values to show.
and I do have five hundred seconds waveform file which size is 500*11025 (int32), and when I playing it that's hearing not thing.
and I playing the normal waveform file, it has the sound of it.
So I print them and try to find out the way to explain it.
I would figure that you said the range out, I don't have good experience with waveform. thank you.